# How do I use Linq-to-sql to iterate db records?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I [asked on SO a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595052/what-is-the-preferred-method-of-building-extremely-lightweight-business-object) what was the simplest quickest way to build a wrapper around a recently completed database.  I took the advice and used sqlmetal to build linq classes around my database design.

Now I am having two problems.   One, I don't know LINQ.  And, two, I have been shocked to realize how hard it is to learn.  I have a book on LINQ (Linq In Action by Manning) and it has helped some but at the end of the day it is going to take me a couple of weeks to get traction and I need to make some progress on my project today.

So, I am looking for some help getting started.

Click [HERE](http://www.spearsofttech.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/schema.png) To see my simple database schema.
Click [HERE](http://www.spearsofttech.com/html/code.html) to see the vb class that was generated for the schema.

My needs are simple.  I have a console app. The main table is the SupplyModel table.  Most of the other tables are child tables of the SupplyModel table.

I want to iterate through each of Supply Model records.   I want to grab the data for a supply model and then **DoStuff** with the data.  And I also need to iterate through the child records, for each supply model, for example the NumberedInventories and **DoStuff** with that as well.

I need help doing this in VB rather than C# if possible.  I am not looking for the whole solution...if you can supply a couple of code-snippets to get me on my way that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
For the record I have already written the following code...

```
Dim _dataContext As DataContext = New DataContext(ConnectionStrings("SupplyModelDB").ConnectionString)
Dim SMs As Table(Of Data.SupplyModels) = _dataContext.GetTable(Of Data.SupplyModels)()
Dim query = From sm In SMs Where sm.SupplyModelID = 1 Select sm
```

This code is working...I have a query object and I can use ObjectDumper to enumerate and dump the data...but I still can't figure it out...because ObjectDumper uses reflection and other language constructs I don't get.  It DOES enumerate both the parent and child data just like I want (when level=2).

PLEASE HELP...I'M stuck.  Help!

Seth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C# it would be:

```
    var result = from s in _dataContent.SupplyModels where s.SupplyModelID==1 select s;
    foreach(SupplyModel item in result)
    {
       // do stuff
       foreach(SupplyModelChild child in item.SupplyModelChilds)
       {
          //do more stuff on the child
       }
    }
```

and a VB.NET version (from the Telerik code converter)

```
Dim result As var = From s In _dataContent.SupplyModels _
    Where s.SupplyModelID = 1 _
    Select s
For Each item As SupplyModel In result
    ' do stuff
            'do more stuff on the child
    For Each child As SupplyModelChild In item.SupplyModelChilds
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thanks...that did it...that was simple...the problem is that most of my code was using implicit typing which means I did not know what kind of types were being referenced and no intellisense.